# How to get the latest release date of a github repo

Tags: date, github, discord.js, release

For my discord.js bot I want a way to get the latest GitHub release date, but the repo is private on an organization and I want a simple way, maybe using `child_process.exec` could do that but I don't find anything on the Internet.

I just want the date, in timestamp or in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a HTTP request to the [GitHub release API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release)

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest

// Example

https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest
```

Then answer will include:

```
"created_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
"published_at": "2013-02-27T19:35:32Z",
```

The publication date should be the one you want.

---

Using the more recent [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/):

```bash
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/releases/latest
```

Example for [`genotrance/px` releases](https://github.com/genotrance/px/releases):

`gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" /repos/genotrance/px/releases/latest --jq ".published_at"`

`2023-02-07T15:59:14Z`